# Using a SQL Server Database Transaction as a C# Lock

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm moving a website to multiple instances. This means I can't use a `lock` anymore to make sure a service doesn't run on top of itself. So I need a way to lock across instances.

I should probably use a background worker with message queues but I feel like that's overkill for this one service.  I'm wondering if I could somehow use a database transaction as a lock. I don't care about speed - I want it to be simple & work.

Here's what I'm thinking of doing:

```
public class MultiInstanceLock : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string lockId;
    private Transaction transaction;
    private LockEntity lockEntity;

    public MultiInstanceLock(String _lockId)
    {
        lockId = _lockId;

        transaction = new Transaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead, lockId);
        lockEntity = new LockEntity(lockId);
        if(lockEntity.IsNew)
            lockEntity.Id = lockId;

        lockEntity.LockedOn = DateTime.Now;
        lockEntity.Save();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (lockEntity != null)
        {
            lockEntity.UnlockedOn = DateTime.Now;
            lockEntity.Save();
        }

        if(transaction != null)
            transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Here's the usage:

```
using(var l = new MultiInstanceLock("Foo"))
{
    ...do foo...
}
```

Would this work? Is there a better way?

*Already I'm noticing that the transaction would apply to any DB access inside my using statement, which is a bummer.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at SQL Server applocks- exactly what you need (attempt to lock a named resource).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx

We wrote a little IDisposable wrapper around this to make acquisition and cleanup easier.

Comment: Thanks Matt - Any chance you'd share your wrapper?

Comment: Sorry- our wrapper is tied into a bunch of internal infrastructure that I can't post. Here's a link to something similar, though: http://interlace.googlecode.com/svn-history/r38/trunk/source/library/Interlace/DatabaseManagement/DatabaseLock.cs

Comment: Following Matt's advice I created a simple wrapper of `sp_getapplock` & it works perfectly: http://pastie.org/4811362

Comment: @bendytree if you still have that wrapper, could you add it to your answer, 
 That's exactly what I'm looking for.   pastie.org died a couple years ago, and the other example is a dead link too :-(

Comment: For future readers: There is a library which offers (distrbuted) locking strategies: https://github.com/madelson/DistributedLock. The Distrbuted Semaphore locks are also based on sp_getapplock mechanism